# Powershell Regular Expression to replace what's between > and <

Tags: regex, powershell, text, replace

I'm trying to create an regular expression that will replace the text between two tags (> and <) in a text string with whatever I need to replace it with like "My new text". I'm afraid that I'm not very well versed in regular expressions and any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know powershell, but something like `s/>.*?</>my new text<` would be the general regex

Comment: Note that this will not work when there are nested tags (e.g. `<i>my <b>old</b> text</i>`). This scenario can't be covered with regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might help: (edited for correction after comment)

```
>> "<a>my text</a>" -replace ">.*?(<)", '>your text$1'
<a>your text</a>
>>
```

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers No I didn't, my mistake. I'll see it corrected.

Comment: that's the expression I'm looking for, tyvm!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to control match constraint is with a negated class.  If it's multi-line data, us the (m?) option:

```
$text = @'
<i>Some old text 
that I want to replace
with my 
new text </i>
'@

$regex='(m?)>[^<]+<'

$text -replace $regex,'>My new text<'

<i>My new text</i>
```

The '>[^,]+<' translates to "> followed by one or more of anything that isn't <, followed by <".